# Save the most recent object in localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, local-storage

Hey Im building a flipbook type application using html canvas in react the thing is that when i save an object(drawin) form the canvas into local storage it will save not only the next project but also the previous one that has been passed from `handleCreateNewCanvas` function that it is going to pass the object form the previous canvas to the new a new empty canvas as a reference form previous drawing

```
  saveCanvas = () => {
    if (this.canvasRef.current) {
      const saveData = this.canvasRef.current.getSaveData();
      const loadedSaveData = localStorage.getItem('canvasSaveData');
      const parsedData = JSON.parse(saveData);
      const loadedData = JSON.parse(loadedSaveData);
  
      // Check if the loaded data exists and has a newer version
      if (loadedData && parsedData.version > loadedData.version) {
        localStorage.setItem('canvasSaveData', saveData);
      } else if (!loadedData) {
        localStorage.setItem('canvasSaveData', saveData);
      }
    }
  };
```

```
  handleCreateNewCanvas = () => {
    // Make the drawing content transparent
    const saveData = localStorage.getItem('canvasSaveData');
    if (saveData) {
      const parsedData = JSON.parse(saveData);
      let brushColor = parsedData.lines[0].brushColor;
      if (brushColor === "#444") {
        parsedData.lines[0].brushColor = "grey";
      }
      const modifiedSaveData = JSON.stringify(parsedData);
      console.log(modifiedSaveData)
      localStorage.setItem("canvasSaveData", modifiedSaveData);
      this.canvasRef.current.loadSaveData(modifiedSaveData, true);
    }
  };
```

is there any change a should make to the `saveCanvas` function in order to make it save only what is being drawn in the the canvas and ignore the content of the object passed form the `handleCreateNewCanvas` function?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the `saveCanvas` function save only the current drawing and ignore the data passed from `handleCreateNewCanvas` you can use this code.

```
saveCanvas = () => {
  if (this.canvasRef.current) {
    const saveData = this.canvasRef.current.getSaveData();
    const loadedSaveData = localStorage.getItem('canvasSaveData');
    const parsedData = JSON.parse(saveData);
    const loadedData = JSON.parse(loadedSaveData);

    // Check if the loaded data exists and has a newer version
    if (!loadedData || parsedData.version > loadedData.version) {
      // Remove the unnecessary properties from parsedData
      parsedData.lines = parsedData.lines || [];
      parsedData.objects = [];

      const modifiedSaveData = JSON.stringify(parsedData);
      localStorage.setItem('canvasSaveData', modifiedSaveData);
    }
  }
};
```